# ObjectID with mongoskin

Tags: mongodb, mongoskin

Why does this query not work in Mongoskin? (where itemID is a Mongo `ObjectID`)

```
{"_id": itemID}
```

I know that there is truly an element that has a matching `_id` because if I run this same query through the MongoDB shell it works.  Why doesn't it work with Mongoskin?

Answer (score 2):

```
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
```

Notice: the name of the factory function is **ObjectID**, instead of ObjectId

---

Then you can use:

```
db.collection('XXX').update({_id: ObjectId(XXX)}, {$set: {XXX : XXX}});
```

Well, **db** is a wrapped function of mongoskin:

```
module.exports = (function() {

    return require('mongoskin').db('mongodb://localhost:27017/db_name');

})();
```

Comment: Now I suggest using mongoose instead.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that mongoskin uses a different type of `ObjectID` than vanilla mongoDB.  I was using another library to convert my string to an `ObjectID`, hence the confusion.  Here's what worked for me to get the proper `ObjectID` object:

```
require('mongoskin').ObjectID.createFromHexString(hexString);
```